# Best practice, how to setup a rails form with a select to manage a references_one mongoid association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I am trying to setup a form with a select for a simple association in mongoid.

Let assume this model:

```
class dog
  field: name 
  references_one: owner
end

class owner
  field: name
  referenced_in :dog
end
```

Now on my form to create/edit a dog I would like to build a select that list all the owner and allows for the association to be completed:

```
    = f.label "Owner"       
    = f.select :owner, Owner.list_all_owner
```

What should the value of the select be for this to work ? I tried everything, the id, the JSON::ObjectId, etc.

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
= f.collection_select :owner_id, Owner.all, :id, :name
```

?

Comment: it does not works, I did this: = f.collection_select :owner, Owner.all, :id, :name, I can't put :owner_id because it's not part of my model ? What this does is create a select drop down and use the content id as the value. But obviously this does not work and the value is not retain upon save :(

Comment: what about f.collection_select :owner, Owner.all, :name, :id (reversed name & id in the parameter list). I believe the label to use in the drop down comes before the value to associate with that label.